# I am trying to configure Nginx ingress controller on AKS without HELM, I am using manifest files from official nginx website

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
```

```html
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - discovery.k8s.io
  resources:
  - endpointslices
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - update
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
  - list
- apiGroups:
  - coordination.k8s.io
  resources:
  - leases
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - update
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - k8s.nginx.org
  resources:
  - virtualservers
  - virtualserverroutes
  - globalconfigurations
  - transportservers
  - policies
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - k8s.nginx.org
  resources:
  - virtualservers/status
  - virtualserverroutes/status
  - policies/status
  - transportservers/status
  - dnsendpoints/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingressclasses
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
    - cis.f5.com
  resources:
    - ingresslinks
  verbs:
    - list
    - watch
    - get
- apiGroups:
    - cert-manager.io
  resources:
    - certificates
  verbs:
    - list
    - watch
    - get
    - update
    - create
    - delete
- apiGroups:
    - externaldns.nginx.org
  resources:
    - dnsendpoints
  verbs:
    - list
    - watch
    - get
    - update
    - create
    - delete
- apiGroups:
  - externaldns.nginx.org
  resources:
  - dnsendpoints/status
  verbs:
  - update
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-ingress
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I am trying to configure the Nginx ingress controller on AKS without HELM, I am using manifest files from the official Nginx website

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
     #annotations:
       #prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
       #prometheus.io/port: "9113"
       #prometheus.io/scheme: http
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      containers:
      - image: nginx/nginx-ingress:2.4.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        - name: readiness-port
          containerPort: 8081
        - name: prometheus
          containerPort: 9113
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /nginx-ready
            port: readiness-port
          periodSeconds: 1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "128Mi"
         #limits:
         #  cpu: "1"
         #  memory: "1Gi"
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          runAsUser: 101 #nginx
          runAsNonRoot: true
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
```

I am getting a weird issue, it seems the pod is not able to find the config map (both the pod & the config map are in the same namespace)

```html
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
```

[image: Error]

I tried to multiple times by deleting ns and recreating no luck

Comment: Can you share the manifest files?

Comment: I have added manifest can you please check

Comment: How is the service account configured: serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress?

Comment: yes nginx-ingress

Comment: do you have the manifest for that also? and the bindings

Comment: Added SA and role binding manifest

Comment: And they are also applied in your AKS I assume?

Comment: yes it is applied on AKS

Comment: Sorry then I don't have any more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

what if you just mount it, directly since its on the same ns?

```
spec:
      ---
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
```